# Is it bad for columns in composite keys to have mismatching types?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

Problem:
I'd like to make a composite primary key from columns `id` and `user_id` for a postgres database table. Column `user_id` is a foreign key with an integer type, whereas `id` is a string.  Will this cause a conflict because the types are different?

Edit: Also, are there combinations of types that would cause problems?

Context:
I obviously should match the type of the `User.id` field for its foreign key. And, the `id` for my table will be derived from a uuid to prevent data leaks. So I would prefer not to change the types of either field I want in this table.

Research:
I am using sqlalchemy. Their documentation mentions how to create a composite primary key, but it doesn't discuss dealing with different types for each column.

Comment: I would assume mismatching types are fine because database records are considered to be tuples, so a composite key would probably be a tuple, as well. So it seems it should be type-agnostic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this won't be a problem.

Your question seems to indicate that you think, the values of the indexed columns are somehow concatenated and then stored in the index as a single value. This is not the case. Each column value is stored independently but together. Similar to the way the column values are stored in the actual table.